# Events only being detected by single instance of class

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to write an abstract class that contains data common to multiple components of an application and provides the ability for those components to notify other components that the data they're working on has changed. Unfortunately, none of the other components are picking up the events being fired. I decided to write up a quick test to see if I could pinpoint what was wrong, but I'm running into the exact same issues. Am I misunderstanding how events work? Or am I missing something obvious?

```
void Main()
{
    EventHandler<string> EVENT = delegate {};
    var test = new DerivedClass("test", ref EVENT, 6);
    var test2 = new DerivedClass("test2", ref EVENT, 8);
    test.Number = 7;
    test2.Number = 4;
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void OnChanged(object sender, string e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Derived class event fired from {0}! New value is {1}", sender, e));
    }

    public DerivedClass(string name, ref EventHandler<string> handler, int val) : base(ref handler, val)
    {
        this._name = _name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }
    string _name;
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual int Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set
        {
            _handler(this, value);
            _number = value;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnChanged(object sender, string e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base class event fired! " + e);
    }

    protected BaseClass(ref EventHandler<string> handler, int val)
    {
        _number = val;
        _handler = handler;
        if (_handler != null) _handler += this.OnChanged;
    }

    protected event EventHandler<string> _handler;
    protected int _number;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "A BaseClass";
    }
}
```

> output:

```
Derived class event fired from test! New value is 7
Derived class event fired from test2! New value is 4
```

Comment: I don't see what is wrong, it looks like your output matches your code perfectly. What did you expect it to do? By the way, passing and assigning the event like that isn't standard C# event practice, you always use += (= can be used to clear out the multicast delegate, but is generally discouraged)

Comment: I expected the event to fire on both DerivedClasses. Creating a static event worked, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I misunderstanding how events work?

Probably. Specifically, you seem to be under the impression either that events are handled on a per-class basis, or that child class instances will all share the same parent class instance.

You've declared your event to be non-`static`:

```
protected event EventHandler<string> _handler;
```

So every instance of any class that extends this class will have its own instance of this event. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you might consider making the event static?